# Add text field on view site then save

Tags: php, joomla

I'm developing a Joomla component for grading. I have 3 views:

- Course
- Subject
- Student

The "course" and "subject" views are now working fine but I have a little problem with the student view. I am tasked to create or add a text field in the default view of it, and I have successfully done it, but the problem is when I add JToolbarHelper::save it does not save or update the item that was in the text field.. are there any solutions to this?

here is the sample code

`echo "<input type='text' name='grade' value='".$row->grade."'>"`

Answer (score 0):

Can u please refer your `STUDENT` XML file. If there is no filed like `grade` you have to create it. After submit your form you will get the post values...

In `Joomla 2.5` you have declare all fields in XML file.

- Put `exit`  befor the from submission and `echo $this->grade` the value. If the value is not there just put `$this->grade = $_POST['grade']`. Then the value was store in database table.

Try this... Hope this will works for you....